# java.lang.NullPointerException in EntityManagerFactory

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, persistence, entitymanager

I am new at JSF . I am trying to use persistence. Here my entity class. When I run this class it returns null.

```
enter code here public EntityManager getEm() {
      try {
    persistenceUnitName = em.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties().get("hibernate.jpa.persistenceUnitName").toString();      
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
    em = emf.createEntityManager();       
    System.out.println("EM Success");

    } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e);
    }

    return em;
}
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "GKN-MIA-NBAPU")
public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    DB_connection obj_DB_connection=new DB_connection();
   // System.out.println(obj_DB_connection.get_connection());
    System.out.println("Entity manager connection"+obj_DB_connection.getEm());

}
```

And Output:
[t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcs99.png)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with jsf.

Comment: Oky thanks for comment. I did not say it is only about the jsf. I am using JSF and I need to establish database connection with persistence.@Kukeltje

Comment: If ypu tag it with jsf, you imply jsf is part of the proble, tags are for that, not for what you use.

Comment: I know but I did not put JSF as a tag in here...

Comment: Yes you did. The original question had it